# How to calculate time stamp difference in Elasticserarh +Kibana and show it in new column i n results

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Suppose we have two time stamps fields, can we calculate difference of time between them? For
example

[2014-04-01T18:50:41.817+0000] ~[2014-04-01T18:50:45.680Z]

Answer (score 3):

I struggled to achieve this, but found a way.

```
ruby {
  code => 'event["buffer_time"] = Time.now.to_f - event["arrival_ts"].to_f'
}
```

The code above is no longer supported in latest versions as of today - Logstash-7.x.

We can achieve the same with event.set and event.get in ruby
and converting timestamp (datetime) using the time library

```
ruby { 
    init => "require 'time'"
    code => '
    to_date_v   = Time.iso8601(event.get("[B-date]").to_s).to_i
    from_date_v = Time.iso8601(event.get("[A-date]").to_s).to_i
    
    event.set("[to_date]", to_date_v)
    event.set("[from_date]", from_date_v)

    difference_v = to_date_v - from_date_v
    event.set("[difference]", difference_v)
    '
    }
```

You can check sample input, output and the complete script [here](https://github.com/superriya/logstash-elasticsearch-api-data)

Answer (score 0):

They decided to disable server scripts in elasticsearch as a security precaution.  You can use lucene expressions, but they only work for integers (not dates).

I would compute the difference between the two dates in a ruby{} filter in logstash, so you're not at the whim of elasticsearch/kibana.

```
  ruby {
    code => "

      begin

        event['elapsed_time'] = ((DateTime.parse(event['date2']) - DateTime.parse(event['date1'])) * 86400).to_i

      rescue Exception => e

        event['logstash_ruby_exception'] = 'elapsed: ' + e.message

      end

    "
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned this from R.Clarke from elastic (version logstash 2.1.0):

```
ruby {
  code => 'event["buffer_time"] = Time.now.to_f - event["arrival_ts"].to_f'
}
```